# IOS - file and folder management

Tags: ios, ipad, nsfilemanager, directory

I am learning how to create and manage files and folders in ios right now. But I cannot seems to do the folder part right. What is wrong with my code below?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *dataFile;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSString *newDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    BOOL isDir;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Identify the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the data file
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:@"newfolder" isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
    NSLog(@"folder already created!");
}else{
    NSLog(@"create new folder now...");
    newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newfolder"];
}

dataFile = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
            @"/newfolder/datafile.dat"];

// Check if the file already exists
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFile])
{
    // Read file contents and display in textBox
    NSData *databuffer;
    databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: dataFile];

    NSString *datastring = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithData: databuffer
                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    _textBox.text = datastring;
}

}


- (IBAction)saveText:(id)sender {
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSData *databuffer;
    NSString *dataFile;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    dataFile = [docsDir
                stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"/newfolder/datafile.dat"];
    databuffer = [_textBox.text
                  dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [filemgr createFileAtPath: dataFile
                     contents: databuffer attributes:nil];
}
```

I am not sure what happen but everytime i run the simulation it give me a blank text field eventhough I already put in some text before. I followed the the tutorial from [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_6_iPad_Directory_Handling_and_File_I/O_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example) and google some other example for the directories creation part. What seems to go wrong?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is in This line:

```
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:@"newfolder" isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
    NSLog(@"folder already created!");
```

> You need to pass the complete path as argument of `fileExistsAtPath` Like:

```
NSSTring *folderPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
            @"newfolder"];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:folderPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        NSLog(@"folder already created!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are updated working version, in case anyone is looking for it:

```
newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newfolder"];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:newDir isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        NSLog(@"folder already created!");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"create new folder now...");
        [filemgr createDirectoryAtPath:newDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                            attributes:nil error: NULL];

    }
```

Comment: This should be part of your question, not an additional answer.  All it does is insert the information contained in the other answer.